# Why does it crash after last enemy is killed? [space invaders]

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to coding and am having trouble figuring out why my game crashes after the last enemy is killed. I am making a space invaders game for my final project for school. For now, i was just trying to get the top row of enemies to shoot every so often and it worked, however when the last enemy is killed in the top row, i get an error code. From what i understand it is like the program is trying to remove an enemy laser that is not there and then i get the error code ----> list.remove(x): x not in list. Please help thank you

```
def level1():

    # Images
    bg = pygame.image.load('spacebackground.jpg')

    bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1024, 768))
    ship1 = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
    ship1 = pygame.transform.scale(ship1, (50, 50))
    life1 = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
    life1 = pygame.transform.scale(life1, (25, 25))
    life2 = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
    life2 = pygame.transform.scale(life2, (25, 25))
    enemy1 = pygame.image.load('enemy1.png')
    enemy1 = pygame.transform.scale(enemy1, (50, 50))
    enemy2 = pygame.image.load('enemy2.png')
    enemy2 = pygame.transform.scale(enemy2, (50, 50))
    points = 0

    # Coordinates
    enemy_x = 50
    enemy_x2 = 50
    enemy_x3 = 50
    dx = 5
    dx2 = 10
    dx3 = 5
    shipX = 462
    shipY = 668

    # Lists
    enemies = []
    enemies_2 = []
    enemies_3 = []
    enemyLaser1 = []
    enemyLaser2 = []
    enemyLaser3 = []
    lasers = []

    # Appending enemies
    for i in range(10):
        enemies.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x, 100, 50, 50))
        enemy_x += 65
    for i in range(10):
        enemies_2.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x2, 150, 50, 50))
        enemy_x2 += 65
    for i in range(10):
        enemies_3.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x3, 225, 50, 50))
        enemy_x3 += 65

    # Game Loop
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)

        # Laser Coordinates
        laserX = shipX + 23
        laserY = 658

        # Event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            # Creating lasers with space bar
            if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]) != 0 and len(lasers) < 3:
                lasers.append(pygame.Rect(laserX, laserY, 5, 20))

        # Ship Rect
        shipRect = pygame.Rect(shipX, shipY, 50, 50)

        # Ship Controls
        if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]) != 0:
            shipX += 20
        if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]) != 0:
            shipX += -20

        # Removing enemies and lasers when collision
        for enemy in enemies:
            for laser in lasers:
                if laser.colliderect(enemy):
                    enemies.remove(enemy)
                    lasers.remove(laser)
                    points += 5
                    break
        for enemy_2 in enemies_2:
            for laser in lasers:
                if laser.colliderect(enemy_2):
                    enemies_2.remove(enemy_2)
                    lasers.remove(laser)
                    points += 10
                    break
        for enemy_3 in enemies_3:
            for laser in lasers:
                if laser.colliderect(enemy_3):
                    enemies_3.remove(enemy_3)
                    lasers.remove(laser)
                    points += 5
                    break

        # Moving laser
        for laser in lasers:
            laser.move_ip(0, -10)

        # Removing laser when off screen
        for laser in lasers:
            if laser.y <= -20:
                lasers.remove(laser)

        # Keeping ship on screen
        if shipX <= 0:
            shipX = 0
        if shipX >= 974:
            shipX = 974

        # Reversing direction when enemies reach boundary
        if len(enemies) >= 1:
            if enemies[0].x < 50:
                dx = -dx
            if enemies[-1].x > 924:
                dx = -dx
        if len(enemies_2) >= 1:
            if enemies_2[0].x < 50:
                dx2 = -dx2
            if enemies_2[-1].x > 924:
                dx2 = -dx2
        if len(enemies_3) >= 1:
            if enemies_3[0].x < 50:
                dx3 = -dx3
            if enemies_3[-1].x > 924:
                dx3 = -dx3

        # Move each enemy
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.x += dx
        for enemy_2 in enemies_2:
            enemy_2.x += dx2
        for enemy_3 in enemies_3:
            enemy_3.x += dx3

        # Enemy Shooting
        if len(enemies) >= 1:
            randEnemy1 = random.randrange(len(enemies))
        if len(enemies_2) >= 1:
            randEnemy2 = random.randrange(len(enemies_2))
        if len(enemies_3) >= 1:
            randEnemy3 = random.randrange(len(enemies_3))

        if len(enemies) >= 0:
            for enemy in enemies:
                if enemy == enemies[randEnemy1] and len(enemyLaser1) < 3:
                    enemyLaser1.append(pygame.Rect(enemy.x + 22.5, 120, 5, 20))

        for enemyLaser in enemyLaser1:
            enemyLaser.move_ip(0, 10)
        if enemyLaser.y >= 769:
            enemyLaser1.remove(enemyLaser)

        # Drawing
        screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
        for laser in lasers:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, laser)
        for enemyLaser in enemyLaser1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, enemyLaser)

        screen.blit(ship1, shipRect)
        for enemy in enemies:
            screen.blit(enemy1, enemy)
        for enemy_2 in enemies_2:
            screen.blit(enemy2, enemy_2)
        for enemy_3 in enemies_3:
            screen.blit(enemy1, enemy_3)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("OCR A Extended", 30)
        pointsFont = font.render("Points:"+ str(points), 1, red)
        screen.blit(life1, (5,733))
        screen.blit(life2, (33,733))
        screen.blit(pointsFont, (5, 5))

        # Update Display
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You're going to need to do some old fashioned debugging. You could start with opening a log file and record messages as you add and remove objects to lists and see if you can catch your logic error.  You may also need  to use pdb, or you could try pudb which is a little friendlier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
for enemy in enemies:
        for laser in lasers:
            if laser.colliderect(enemy):
                enemies.remove(enemy)
                lasers.remove(laser)
```

After the first enemy you loop again but the lasers have been removed.  You need to create a class and set a flag that sets them active/inactive rather than removing them, and then later remove them.